# Why did this nun hear a confession?

Tags: annabelle-creation, the-conjuring-universe

In *Annabelle: Creation*, Janice confesses to Sister Charlotte.

But is a nun even allowed to hear confessions? Don't you need a priest for that?

Comment: http://www.catholicplanet.com/information/Confession-instruction.pdf - No, they can't.

Comment: You can confess to anybody who will listen. Of course, only a priest can confer divine forgiveness, and restore your soul to a state of grace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was addressed in a roundtable discussion with the film's director and the actress portraying the nun.

> **Q. The whole idea of saying confession to you to me made me think, “She’s not a priest. Why would she say that to you?”**
>
> **David F. Sandberg:** *Well, we don’t have a priest around. They’re improvising.*
>
> **Stephanie Sigman:** *It’s not that traditional, I think. She’s not that traditional nun.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Annabelle: Creation: Roundtable Interview With Director David F. Sandberg And Stephanie Sigman](http://art.eviranews.com/news/Annabelle:-Creation:-Roundtable-Interview-With-Director-David-F.-Sandberg-and-Stephanie-Sigman/)</sup></sub>